# how could i save unlimit toggle buttons state after restart app?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm making bucket list application which it creates a toggle button for every task, so if you press on the button it change from state "false" to "true" but how could i save their states so they don't change after restart the app ?
it worked just fine for a single button, but how can i make it work for every Toggle button which connected to the listview?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TaskDbHelper mHelper;
private ListView mTaskListView;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
SharedPreferences sp;
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mHelper = new TaskDbHelper(this);
    updateUI();
    LayoutInflater myinflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View myview = myinflater.inflate(R.layout.item_todo, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.lld),false);
    ToggleButton togglebut = (ToggleButton) myview.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    sp = getSharedPreferences("sp",MainActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);

                                      if (sp.getString("sp","").equals("0")){
                                          togglebut.setChecked(true);
                                      } else if (sp.getString("sp","").equals("1")){
                                          togglebut.setChecked(false);
                                      }

                                      if (togglebut.isChecked()){
                                          sp.edit().putString("sp","0").apply();
                                      } else {sp.edit().putString("sp","0").apply();
                                      }


    togglebut.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            sp = getSharedPreferences("sp",MainActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            if (isChecked){
                sp.edit().putString("sp","0").apply();
            } else {
                sp.edit().putString("sp","1").apply();
            }
                                          }
                                      });
    }
```

Comment: Why not in the database where the tasks are defined? Could have a 'completed' column in there.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a SharedPreference to keep the state of the button.

This goes above OnCreate:

```
SharedPreference sp;
```

This goes in OnCreate:

```
    sp = getSharedPreferences("sp",Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String newsp = noise.getString("sp","");
    int spnum;
    try{
        spnum = Integer.parseInt(newsp);
    }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        spnum = 0;
    }
    sp.edit().putString("sp",Integer.toString(spnum)).apply();

    ToggleButton togglebut = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebut);


        if (sp.getString("sp","").equals("0")){
            togglebut.setChecked(true);
        } else if (sp.getString("sp","").equals("1")){
            togglebut.setChecked(false);
           }

        if (togglebut.isChecked()){
            sp.edit().putString("sp","0").apply();
        } else {sp.edit().putString("sp","0").apply();
           }


        togglebut.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                    sp = getSharedPreferences("sp",Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    if (isChecked){
                        sp.edit().putString("sp","0").apply();
                    } else {
                        sp.edit().putString("sp","1").apply();
                    }

                }
            });
```

Comment: thank you very much mr Carter for your time, i don't know what i did wrong i put this code after #create and modified the names but keep crashing when i start it on the emulator. :(

Comment: Oh i left out the ending of the OnClick!! if you copied it directly, thats why it didnt work! I'll edit it right now! @MuradAlburki

Comment: it works just fine if i use the code for a specific toggle button, but in my app every time user add task it generate a toggle button and delete button , so i have xml just for those two, i tried this code after create and modified the toggle button id "doesn't work", i tried to put it under OnClick code "doesn't work also", i tried to debug it, toggle button state stuck at null value . is there is any way that i could use this code for regenerated toggle button ?

Comment: What do you mean by regenerated? Also i just edited it and added another part that might fix the 'null' problem.

Comment: i mean that i have a main activity with a list view and another xml file with a text and a toggle button, so every time i add a task it creates a task with a new toggle button.
 i edited the code in question up there, but the app still can not manage to recover the toggle buttons states when i restart it. "thank you very much"